# how to configure separate swap partitions on two Ubuntu OS's 20.04.1 and 20.10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, swap

I have windows 10 preinstalled, later installed 20.4.1 LTS and 20.10 creating separate swap partitions for both Ubuntu OS's, but only one swap partition is being used by both Linux OS's as shown by the UUID on both 20.04.1 and 20.10. and not sure if that could cause any issue in some context, but want to make sure both use their own specified swap partitions.

**This is on Ubuntu 20.04.1**

```
@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/fstab
<file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=68c59802-de04-4349-b8a6-e0ba62bd16f7  / ext4  errors=remount-ro  0  1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=AECF-7CBC  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=0bc06c35-9a9e-44c0-828f-e17e1e19ce96 none  swap    sw        0       0
```

**This is on Groovy Gorrila**

```
gorilla:$ cat /etc/fstab
<file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=efd12cbc-6f96-48ac-ba7e-de6e6b8aff16  /  ext4  errors=remount-ro 0  1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=AECF-7CBC  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=0bc06c35-9a9e-44c0-828f-e17e1e19ce96 none swap  sw 0       0
# swap was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=82395590-c296-4ea6-911c-dfb36b0773d0 none swap  sw 0       0
```

Comment: Look in /etc/fstab on both Ubuntu instances, if swap has same UUID (or same device name /dev/sdX) they uses same partition. Please update your question with the content of fstab for both instances.

Comment: I have found that Ubuntu will try using every swap partition on a drive unless limited by fstab. You can use Disks to turn swap on or off in fstab. Specifying a swap partition in fstab should disable other swap partitions. Why are you using two swap partitions? One is enough for both versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Am completely new to Linux community and i just followed the installation method as a recommendation suggested by a colleague, i actually wanted to do hibernation on both the OS's maybe that would be the reason for different swap partition for each OS's

Comment: What does `sudo swapon -s` say when booted from either version? With Groovy Gorilla fstab, try putting a `#` in front of the sda7 swap line. so only one swap partition is loaded.

Comment: Filename    Type  Size Used Priority
/dev/sdb7                               partition 8000508 0 -2

Comment: Just make sure that each OS has only the swap partition in its `fstab` that it should use. Where two swaps are indicated, the system will use both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete these two lines from /etc/fstab in Groovy Gorilla_

```
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=0bc06c35-9a9e-44c0-828f-e17e1e19ce96 none swap  sw 0       0
```

So that it has only one swap definition, and they are different.